# Must the interaction of the $D$-brane be done through the closed or the open strings?

Tags: string-theory, interactions, branes

The interaction of the D brane was through the closed or open strings. However, as a distinct object, why the D brane could not have some sort of interaction themselves? i.e. an incident energy when they collide?

In the $T$-dual space, if two D brane in the $25$ th direction $X'_{25}$ and $Y'_{25}$ completely collide, there's more massless fields, but could there by some type of divergence from the analogy of the cosmier energy? (i.e. an incident energy)

In the usual coordinates, the D brane was not necessarily at any fixed location, what if the two hyper surface incident at an angle, (heuristically, of course) could the free varying in the $26-1$ directions interact through the fluctuation?

Does the interaction of the D brane must be done through the closed or open strings?